# Ручная конвертация xml в xliff

Tags: xml, конвертация

Проблема следующая поступил файл от клиента в формате xml, нужно сделать из него файл формата xliff а после нужно будет вернуть файл к исходному виду.

1) Как выглядит процесс этой двойной конвертации файла?
2) Сколько действий занимает и как они выглядят при конвертации в ручную ?
3) Как вычислить время на ручную конвертацию в зависимости от кол-ва строк необходимых к конвертации?

Comment: Попробуйте вот эту программу https://www.maxprograms.com/support/swordfish/convert_to_xliff.html

Comment: Мне нужен ответ как если бы мне надо было дать ТЗ для разработчика. Очевидно не используя никакие сторонние программы, возможно использование  rest api этих сервисов, однако вся  магия должна происходить на локальном уровне

Comment: Собственно вы тогда должны описать как поля xml переходят в поля xliff.

Comment: а это мысль надо почитать